# How to send inputs in recursive way to the parameter while invoking API

Tags: java, json

```
 //I have a property file which takes data for API 
 //sendEmpData=ID,NAME,LNAME,Address  how to send it with multiple request 

test_Iteration=3
parameterList=ID,NAME,Address
parameterVal=1111,2222,333/AAA,BBB, ,/USA,,LON 

//I want to send the 3 inputs one by one as follows 
sendEmpData=1111,AAA,USA
sendEmpData=2222,BBB,null
sendEmpData=2222,BBB,LON
```

//How to write in java which will send input like this

Comment: The question is to know, how to send request to API in an iterated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something in these lines.  Syntax is not tested..

```
public class searchOrgData extends runautomationAPI
{
protected static String searchDataAPIURL;
private static String line="";
private static StringBuffer result;
public void getOrgData() throws Exception{
generateToken get_authenticationKey = new generateToken();
get_authenticationKey.getToken();
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream  = null;
inputStream  = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
prop.load(inputStream );
searchDataAPIURL = prop.getProperty("searchDataAPIURL");

//Create a list of strings here
List<String[]> arrayList = new List<String[]>();
private String[] test1= {"123", "ABC", "USA"};
private String[] test2= {"", "BGD", "UK"};
arrayList.add(test1);
arrayList.add(test2);

for (String[] arr : arrayList)
{
string ID= arr[0]; 
string name= arr[1]; 
string address= arr[2]; 
JSONObject inputParameterList=new JSONObject();
inputParameterList.put("ID", ID));
inputParameterList.put("Name", name);
inputParameterList.put("Address", address);
String jsonData=inputParameterList.toString();
searchOrgData httpPostReq=new searchOrgData();
HttpPost httpPost=httpPostReq.createConnectivity(searchDataAPIURL);
httpPostReq.executeReq( jsonData, httpPost);}
HttpPost createConnectivity(String restUrl){
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(restUrl);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+ access_key);
return post;
}
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a bit more here....after creating list i have scenarios of different inputs to different parameters, and to invoke request for each of the flavor

Comment: So you create the List of Arrays.  Create your array with data for one test. Then add that array to the list. when you run the foreach loop, you can get and save output / return of each array(test data)

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I have updated the answer.